# Selendroid Android testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apk, selendroid

I am new to Mobile automation. Would like to know if we can test Web based mobile application using Selendroid?Also is Android studio and apk for AUT is necessary? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Selendroid for Native and Mobile WEB Android Apps.
http://selendroid.io/

Their is no need of Android Studio for Selendroid, you can setup the Selendroid environment in your eclipse itself. If you have little knowledge in Selenium webdriver it easy also.

http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selendroid.html

This is the best link i found to start with Selendroid.
Hope it will help you.